# Cross Compiling for Android on Ubuntu

Tags: android, c++, android-5.0-lollipop

I wrote some libraries for a product on window platform (C/C++) product and now i need to build those libraries for Android platform. Totally new to this cross-compiling and also relatively new to linux. I did some searching and found a very helpful link [Android Source](http://source.android.com/source/developing.html). I did this `repo` and also downloaded and synchronized with the source. But now i am stuck what should I do. It took several hours to download the source, which is normal as per many threads on net. Here i need a help that how i can cross-compile my source against this Android? 
Can i use the netbeans Compiler?. 
The host is running Android branch android-5.0.0_r1.0.1. (version Lollipop).

Comment: How is this going to be used?  Normally, 3rd parties only develop code that is called (immediately or ultimately) as a JNI library, so you should use the Android NDK as your cross compiler.  Typically you would only use the AOSP build system if you were integrating at a more fundamental level into Android itself.  If you need to do the latter, you would add your code alongside that existing, create a new Android.mk, etc, and build it with the existing build system.

Comment: Even if you ultimately want to integrate into a system build, if there is a way you *can* start as a simple NDK project, you should do so - it will be faster to develop and test that way, yield build products drastically more portable across devices, and require fewer build dependencies to download and pre-build.  Ultimately it is much easier to later evolve an NDK project into a new module in AOSP, than would be to turn something linked against non-public internals into an NDK project.

Comment: As stated above, Android uses Java NDK to integrate C++ code in Dalvik (its virtual machine). Note that this works very differently than an application on Windows. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899740/android-ndk-tutorial-guide-for-beginners) for some tutorials on NDK.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The Third party gave me their `repo` link and i synchronized with it. They are running Android Lollipop on Qualcom Snapdragon Series Processor. I already Sync with their code and downloaded all the information. Once i cross compiled my code for `Arm` Processor using `arm-linux-gnueabi` compiler in Linux. So, can i do something like this here?.